printf (builtin) prints `-nan` for floating point numbers in Ubuntu 24.10
I have two systems: Ubuntu 24.04 and Ubuntu 24.10. Maybe the locales are different, but this is not related to my problem.
On Ubuntu 24.04:
$ printf "%7d %7.2f %8.3f\n" 123 123.45 45
    123  123.45   45.000

as expected. But, on Ubuntu 24.10:
$ printf "%7d %7.2f %8.3f\n" 123 123.45 45
    123    -nan     -nan

On both systems:
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin

So, it must be related to Bash version (5.2.21(1) vs. 5.2.32(1)).
Is there anybody experiencing the same problem?
Note: /bin/printf seems to work OK on both systems.

Looks like a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/2083131

And likely locale-related. LC_ALL=C printf "%7d %7.2f %8.3f\n" 123 123.45 45 works

No, it does not work (on 24.10) @kos .

Weird, on 24.04 it didn't work for me without LC_ALL=C, but it worked with LC_ALL=C. I'll have to check on Bash's version later as I'm not on that machine anymore.

Works fine in bash 5.2.37 for me (I'm on Arch), so I think this is indeed just a bug that has been fixed in newer versions of bash and there isn't much to do here on AU.

It doesn't work on the machine I'm on right now either by the way, and here LC_ALL=C also fixes it. This is on Ubuntu 22.04.4 / Bash 5.1.16(1)

... possibly related to this Unix&Linux Q&A Bash printf float formatting became nonsensical and random
